# Bullets not print in pdf which generated by jasper report but preview correctly in jasper soft studio

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I am designing a jasper report using jasper (6.1.0) soft studio and jasper report is exported to pdf . Every static text on the report correctly display on pdf .
But bullets(Black squires in the code below ) are not in pdf.

I tried to change the encoding and I tried with font extension as well.

```
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="1" y="221" width="553" height="39" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="4b31d8f1-d37b-4976-87ac-8d8b90d73ee8"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Top" markup="none">
                <font fontName="Allianz Sans" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
                <text>
    <![CDATA[
            ◼  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
            ◼  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
            ◼  cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
]]>
               </text>

        </staticText>
```

## I expected to print pdf (with bullets (black squires))

```
            ◼  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
            ◼  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
            ◼  cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
```

## But result as follow (without bullets (black squires))

```
             aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
             bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
             cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
```

Need a help to find out a reason for this or any solution.

Comment: Are you sure your font supports those squares? Are you sure the pdf is generated with that font? Sometimes pdf exporter won't find the font or it doesn't work for pdf and it gets generated with some default one instead - to check that open the pdf in acrobat reader, right click anywhere -> document properties -> fonts, and see if your font is there.

Comment: @Lasan Looks like font's issue

Comment: .  @Amongalen your reason is correct . I checked that  and its not generated with relevant font I as in jasper report . Its generated with Helvetica , actual font is ArialMT. How can I force to do so. Any tips ?